# CSS/Bootstrap for sizing embedded layout without using webkit flex

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

We have the following layout a client is requiring and we can't seem to get it to work in all browsers.[image]

The blue and yellow sections are images and both of them are they same height. The maroon area is more of a table which contains text/links for each cell. 
For the desktop everything displays perfect.
On an iPhone, the links area doesn't size they way we need it to. Essentially, we need all 3 columns to be the same height and be responsive but what happens is the links section height doesn't get set to the same height as the two image sections and the text in the bottom cell usually gets pushed up into the cell above it. 
In order to get this layout we used flex but safari on the iPhone doesn't seem to format flex the same as chrome on an Android.

This is the code for the last column

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col" style="">               
<div class="flex member-grid responsive-font" style="font-size: 13.9167px;">
<div class="auto" style=""><a style="color: white" href="">TOP SECTION</a>
</div>
<div class="auto" style=""><a style="color: white" href="">2ND SECTION</a>
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs auto"><a style="color: white" href="/donate">3RD 
SECTION</a></div>
<div class="auto" style=""><a style="color: white" href="">4TH SECTION</a>
</div>
<div class="auto" style=""><a style="color: white" href="">5TH SECTION</a>
</div>  <div class="stretch flex" style="/* font-size:25px; *//* line-
height: 24px; */border-bottom: none;">
    <div class="stretch" style="justify-content: flex-end;">BOTTOM 1ST 
ROW</div>
    <div class="stretch" style="/* font-size:18px; */font-weight:100;/* 
 justify-content: flex-start; */">BOTTOM 2ND ROW</div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4? https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/ doesn't list the same classes as what you're using.

Comment: We're using 3.3.7

Comment: We need your CSS too.